# $T_1$ property and local compactness

Tags: general-topology

Recall that a space  $X$ is a locally compact if for every $x\in X$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of the point of $x$ such that $cl U$  is compact subspace of $X$. How we can show that  compact $cl U$ is $T_1$?

Comment: It isn’t true. $X=\{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology is a counterexample.

Comment: But, I see this on the Engelking's book, page 148, under the definition. Could you look at ? Maybe something is wrong.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. Engelking, like some others, defines *compact* to mean *compact Hausdorff*. (This is one of the few things about the book that I really dislike.) The result is true if *locally compact* means that every point has a nbhd whose closure is compact and Hausdorff; I’ve added an answer with the proof of this.

Comment: It seems that (local) compactness is almost irrelevant here; it serves only to sneak the Hausdorff property in by including it as part of the definition of "compact". As Brain Scott's answer shows, what's really going on is that, if $X$ is a space in which each point lies in a closed $T_1$ set, then $X$ is $T_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Engelking defines *compact* to mean what I would call *compact and Hausdorff*. It is true that if each point of a space $X$ has a nbhd $U$ such that $\cl U$ is compact and Hausdorff, then $X$ is $T_1$. More generally, if $X$ is any space, and $x\in X$ has a nbhd $U$ such that $\cl U$ is compact and Hausdorff, then $\{x\}$ is closed in $X$. (Recall that a space is $T_1$ iff each singleton set is closed.)

To see this, let $x\in X$, and let $U$ be a nbhd of $x$ such that $\cl U$ is compact and Hausdorff. The space $\cl U$ with the relative topology inherited from $X$ is a Hausdorff space, so it’s $T_1$, and therefore $\{x\}$ is a closed set in $\cl U$. This means that there is some closed set $F$ in $X$ such that $\{x\}=F\cap\cl U$. But then $\{x\}$ is the intersection of two sets that are closed in $X$, and as such it must itself be closed in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}$ with the digital line topology is a counterexample to this claim. Denote $\mathbb{Z}$ with the digital line topology as: $\mathbb{Z}_{\text{DL}}$ Note that every integer $m$ has a neighborhood contained in a compact subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{\text{DL}}$. If $m$ is odd take the neighborhood to be $\{m\}$ which is contained in $\{m,m+1,m+2\}$, a compact subset. If $m$ is even then take the neighborhood to be $\{m-1,m,m+1\}$ which is contained in $\{m-1,m,m+1\}$, a compact subset.

Think about $2\in \mathbb{Z}$. A compact set containing a neighborhood of $2$ is: $\{1,2,3\}$ Yet $\{1,2,3\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{Z}_{\text{DL}}$ has the following open sets: $\{\{1\},\{1,2,3\},\{3\},\emptyset \} $. We see that $2$ is inextricably linked to $3$ and $1$. Therefore, for the two distinct points $2$ and $3$, there does not exist an open subset $U$ of $\{1,2,3\}$ such that $2\in U$ and $3 \notin U$ so $\{1,2,3\}$ can't be $T_1$.

Comment: But, I see this on the Engelking's book, page 148, under the definition. Could you look at ? Maybe something is wrong.